# Chrome: F6 sends the cursor to the start of omnibox without selecting all text?

Tags: google-chrome

Previously if I pressed <kbd>F6</kbd> while browsing the web I'd get the entire address selected and could quickly change sites. Now, this behaviour has changed so that it only moves the cursor to the beginning of the omnibox without selecting the existing text.

For example, if I'm at `superuser.com` and want to switch to Google, I'm used to just pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> and typing `google` and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, which resulted in `www.google.com`. If I do the same now, the address is `www.googlesuperuser.com`.

How can I revert to the previous style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a new Chrome (Chromium) bug - see [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110540)

Comment: Oh, thanks for the info+link, hope it gets fixed soon!

Comment: Alt+D still does the job.

Comment: You can also use `CTRL + L`.

Look [chrome shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=ien)  > Address bar shortcuts > Jump to the address bar